# How to keep emacsclient alive after file closed?

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

I start `emacs` with `/usr/local/bin/emacs --fg-daemon` via `launchd`, and open `emacsclient` frames in the terminal via `/usr/local/bin/emacsclient -t -s $TMPDIR/emacs$(id -u)/server $filename`.

When I close (via `C-x k` or `C-x #`) the buffer/file that I passed to `emacsclient` when I opened the frame, the frame closes on me.

How can I keep the `emacsclient` frame open after I close the file/buffer I passed when I opened it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, Emacs will delete the client frame when you finish editing the file passed to `emacsclient`.

You can instead open file by

```bash
emacsclient SOME_ARGS_YOU_SPECIFIED \
            --eval '(find-file YOUR-FILENAME)'
```

Or you can write a shell function that passes the filename to `emacsclient` the way described above.